# How to generate XML from UI diagrams like class diagram dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, code-generation

Currently in my team, we are creating the XML files (which runs on the top of customized framework) to do business logic called services. This business logic depends on collection of other services which are already developed.

These services follow a similar pattern to declare variables, to call other services and doing business logic, Like to call a service

```
<service id="Calculator">
    <var declaration>
        <var name="result" />
    </var>
    <call serviceName="Service1-Addition">
        <input>
            <arg1 toVarName="a" value="10"/>
            <arg2 toVarName="b" value="20" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <arg1 fromVarName="result" toVarName="reault" />
        </output>
    </call>
    <logic>
        <if condition="greater_than" arg1="$result" arg2=10 />
    </logic>
</service>
```

*The code above mentioned is a example only*

I am good in developing code in java. Currently, I have developed a java code (ServiceFileGenerator.java), that will accept a service id as input from console and create the template of the service as like below.

In console, it will ask for service name.

```
Please enter the service name : 
Calculator
Service Calculator generated successfully
```

Then I can get the following template in the path mentioned in the java code (ServiceFileGenerator.java).

```
<service id="Calculator">
    <var declaration>

    </var>
    <logic>

    </logic>
</service>
```

I am planning to automate XML code generation process for my project using some UI editor,
So I am planning to or extending any other Class diagram editor, so that each class block represent a service and attribute fields of class block represents the variable declaration block and method declaration block represents the logic block.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: So you want to write a Swing tool to draw diagrams to generate XML files which will in turn allow generating Java code implementing business logic? I would write the business logic directly, in Java, which will allow you to have a readable logic implemented, tested and deployed in a few days rather than an unmaintainable mess of generated code deployed in a few years. Anyway, your question is much too broad.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But my project requirement is like that.

Comment: What [existing tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) have you evaluated?

Comment: I tried this swing based [Violet UML Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/files/violetumleditor/). Now I am thinking to develop in Eclipse plugin by extending Window builder plugin (But I am new to eclipse plugin development also, so need to learn and do). Is there any other speediest/shortest way to achieve this?